# Getting JSON object from a arraylist

Tags: javascript, json, list, vue.js, axios

I have specific problem with axios to getting **JSON object** from my arraylist, so instead of display my `displayName` on my nav bar, it display all **response headers** information, i don't know why ? :

[image]

that my json list from my localhost :

[image]

that my code :

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-nowrap px-3" v-d-toggle.user-actions>
    <img class="user-avatar" src="@/assets/images/avatars/0.jpg" alt="User Avatar"> 
    <span class="d-none d-md-inline-block"></span>{{jsonInfo}}
</a>

<script>
 import axios from 'axios'; 

 export default {
  data() {
  return {
      jsonInfo: [],
      
    }
 },
 mounted () {
  axios
   .get('http://localhost:5000/info/users')
   .then(response => (this.jsonInfo = response))
  
   }
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [axios docs](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema). The response object contains much more than the data that you are requesting. If you are wanting the data in your `jsonInfo` array, you will want `response.data` instead of the full `response` object.

Comment: @b-blox hi, i already try with `response.data` and i obtain empty array on my navbar

Comment: @TheRevenant95 As your data is containing empty array. Hence it is returning an empty array.

Comment: @Rohìt-Jíndal Yep i fix that 